# ant command works from within Eclipse but not from linux command line

Tags: linux, eclipse, ant, command-line

I have a Java project done with Eclipse and I have an ANT command that works perfectly if run from within Eclipse's ANT tool but it doesn't work if I try to run the ANT command from the Linux command line.

Why can it be happening? I have several ANT commands working both in Eclipse and from the command line.

The command is this one:

```
<target name="run.jmsserver">
            <java classname="JMSInternationalEventServer/JMSInternationalEventServer" classpath="${classpath}" fork="true">
            </java>
</target>
```

And classpath is defined previously:

```
<property name="classpath" location="bin:EventReservationCore/bin:EventReservationCore/db:EventReservationCore/lib/*:EventReservationCore/lib/util_iso2.jar:EventReservationCore/lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar:AuthorizationRMI/lib/AuthorizationService.jar"/>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 [java] Could not find the main class: JMSInternationalEventServer.JMSInternationalEventServer.  Program will exit.
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the command you trying to run and what error (if any) are you seeing when you run it?

Comment: I have added the information directly into the question.

Comment: Have you tried expanding `EventReservationCore/lib/*` to the individual jars? Maybe the wildcard expansion isn't working as you'd expect?

Comment: try to use "classpathref" to define the classpath; it refers to a Path-like Structure e.g. `<classpath>`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jason Braucht for your help, the problem was that `EventReservationCore/lib/*` was not working, even if I had read that it should work on Linux.